# How to group data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset and snapshot of a graphic that I am trying to create here:
https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6b668c5c5f6e7cb49a
I am having problems with the grouping option in ggplot2. I just can't seem to put
the plot together. I tried to summarize by month but still couldn't group the values together.
The final graphic can either be all the years in one canvas or in a facet_grid().
This is what I tried:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)

sal <- read_excel("salinity.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")

sal2 <- sal %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01')) + days(day - 1),
         month = month.name[month(date)])
View(sal2)

final <- melt(sal,id.vars=c("year","day","date","month"))
View(final)
names(final)
ggplot(final,aes(date,value,colour=factor(year)),group=month) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the variable "Data" corresponds to in the plot (I used the mean value in the plot below) but apart from that, this is what I would do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

sal <- read_excel("salinity.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")
sal2 <- sal %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year),
         date = as.Date(day, origin = "1995-01-01") -1) %>%
  mutate(Data = rowMeans(select(., `Larv-PLarv`, Adults, Juvenile))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("year","day","date")) %>% 
  filter(year %in% 1995:2005)

ggplot(sal2, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(factor(name, levels = c("Larv-PLarv",
                                                 "Juvenile",
                                                 "Adults",
                                                 "Data"))),
             switch = "y") +
  ylab("Salinity") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1995-01-15"),
                            as.Date("1995-12-15"),
                            by = "1 month"),
               date_labels = "%b")
```

[image: example_1.png]

### Edit

To get each facet in it's own 'box' you can use `facet_wrap()`, e.g.

```
sal2 <- sal %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year),
         date = as.Date(day, origin = "1995-01-01") -1) %>%
  mutate(Data = rowMeans(select(., `Larv-PLarv`, Adults, Juvenile))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("year","day","date")) %>% 
  filter(year %in% 1995:2005)

ggplot(sal2, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~factor(name, levels = c("Larv-PLarv", "Juvenile", "Adults", "Data")), ncol = 1) +
  ylab("Salinity") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1995-01-15"),
                            as.Date("1995-12-15"),
                            by = "1 month"),
               date_labels = "%b") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: This is great thanks you. What should I do if I decide to put each year on its own canvas either using facet_wrap or facet_grid?

Comment: Edited my answer - is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a few hours of work. I up-voted your answer.